# Can anyone tell me how to change default timeout request time in iisnode server?

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

Stuck with this issue.

https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/558

Can anyone help me with the solution.

Comment: That's a long dead project. You should move away from it.

Comment: true, but using this in one of my old. Waana crack a workaround in this issue.

Comment: @LexLi What will you recommend for an alternate solution for this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62450762/11182

Comment: Have you fixed this by use ARR reverse proxy instead?