# Node JS Web Application Unable to Connect to API

Tags: node.js, api, iis, web-applications, backend

I have a node js web application deployed with iis and I have an api for the web application that's running with npm . Everything works on the server and I can access the the website outside the server . However , the web application is not able to connect to API . From the debugging mode in the browser , it says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for the API .

I'm assuming I have the API deployed incorrectly , but I haven't seen any instructions on how to deploy the api with IIS .

Comment: Have you tried to directly enter the url in the browser to access the web api? I suggest you try it and check the result. I also want to know which browser you are using and how you call the api.It may also be a problem when the code is called.

Comment: There are many reason for “ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED” error.
1. If the website is down or temporary not working.
2. You use the wrong url to access the api.
3. The cache in browser affects the access. You can clear browser cache and try to access again.
4. The port used by web api conflicts with other processes. So try to change the port in IIS.

Comment: This error is most likely caused by the client browser, but it does not rule out the web api problem. If all of these are not working, please enable the fail request tracing in IIS  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis  and view the information displayed on the console when the browser accesses the api through F12. These two methods will show you more error messages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450658/how-to-serve-nodejs-application-from-iis-windows-server-edition-os-without-using/62450762#62450762